# Automatically do something instead of mouseover

Tags: mouseover

I downloaded a script for a website and it has this line of code with once i mouseover an image it does something. How can i change it to do it automaticly without me having to mouseover? I can provide full code if needed.

```
$( "body").on( "mouseover", "a", overlay);
```

Comment: This is javascript and jquery

Comment: Well you want it to happen when the document is ready?

Comment: I dont know the github says C 100%. Yes i want it to happen as soon as possible.

Comment: This is not `C`..for sure. I am asking you something else...you want `overlay` to be executed when the document is ready?

Comment: Yes execute overlay when document is ready.